# Users in csv file repeated in Throughput Controller

Tags: csv, jmeter, throughput

I have a csv file with users 1 to 12. And if possible, i want the users to be properly distributed among the controllers.

e.g.
Module1= users 1 to 3

Module2 = users 4 to 6

Module3 = users 7 to 9

Module4 = users 10 to 12

But as observed, the user is being reused in each controller.

Module1 = users 1 to 3

Module2 = users 1 to 3

Module3 = users 1 to 3

Module4 = users 1 to 3

here is my setup

```
Thread Group
|
+Throughput Controller (%execution, 25%,unchecked per user)
|+${username} [Dummy Sampler]
+Throughput Controller (%execution, 25%,unchecked per user)
|+${username} [Dummy Sampler]
+Throughput Controller (%execution, 25%,unchecked per user)
|+${username} [Dummy Sampler]
+Throughput Controller (%execution, 25%,unchecked per user)
|+${username} [Dummy Sampler]
```

Need help, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use instead an [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) using [__threadNum](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function to execute per thread number, for first use expression (1-3):

```
${__groovy(${__threadNum}  < 4)}
```

For second sampler use expression (4-6):

```
${__groovy(${__threadNum}  < 7 && ${__threadNum}  > 3 )}
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to equally distribute different users between requests is going for [Weighted Switch Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/wsc/WeightedSwitchController.md):

[image: JMeter Weighted Switch Controller]

It provides simple way to set so called "weight" - an anticipated frequency of execution for its children which are automatically detected and added so each "Module" will be executed by individual thread each iteration:

[image: JMeter Weighted Swicth Contrroller in action]

See [JMeter’s Weighted Switch Controller - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide) article to learn more. If interested - you can install the Weighted Switch Controller using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)